# Equality case in the Prékopa-Leindler inequality.

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

In the paper ['Remarks on the conjectured log-Brunn-Minkowski inequality'](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.4954) by C. Saraoglou, the author uses the result (Lemma A. 3.) about the equality case in the Prékopa-Leindler inequality. For the proof the reader is sent to a paper written by S. Dubuc. The paper itself is in French, which I don't know, and the case is more general.

QUESTION: Does anybody know a proof of the equality case of Prékopa-Leindler inequality? Or can say where can I find something (preferably in English).

Thank you.